# How can I make hosted .js files entirely private (not password protected or domain-restricted)?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, security, hosting

I'm making a web app and need to call .js files from .html files, but would like some of the .js files to be private (users should not be able to see or download them). The solutions I've found have been for making files password-protected or domain-restricted, but I would like to make them simply inaccessible to everyone. How could I do this?

Comment: it's the internet.. share or leave. simple as that. We should *never* cater to Myrtle's whining 'people look at/store my stuff...' Just as that failed self-inflicted MCafee virus. You know, the blurry pics on FB..

Comment: extra extra... note that.. *even* when you figured out some encryption.. something (a password/phrase) has to unlock the data.. How are you going to ship that (chicken/egg)? Further-more.. suppose through which-craft you managed to do this.. at some point the javascript must be unpacked (in memory) and executed. One would use plain existing tools (often add-ons in the browser) to read the de-crypted data.. (or use a memory editor). There will always be people who will build and explain work-rounds to the general public.

Comment: the easy and reliable way to "make them simply inaccessible to everyone" is to not put them on the web.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

I think that it is not possible protect and use web files at the same time. If you want use it, the user  could find it. That is like to try to protect html code from a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can let users access the files, or you can not let users access the files.
There is no way to let users access the files from a web app without being able to see or download the files.